# Populate two table data using ASP.NET Core

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I want to get two table data in ASP.NET Core. I can get one table detail by using model class. then I can show data by using below code.

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<OrderMaster>>> GetOrderDetails()
{
    return await _context.OrderDetails.ToListAsync();
}
```

So my question is how to get two tables data to the above method? As a example I want to retrieve data for below query:

```sql
select a.ItemDescription,a.Quantity,a.Amount, a.CustomerCode, b.CustomerName,b.CustomerAddress,b.MobileNumber,b.Email from OrderDetails as a left join CustomerDetails as b ON a.CustomerCode=b.CustomerCode
```

Thank you

My model classes

```
public class CustomerMaster
    {
        [Key]
        public int CustomerCode { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
        public string CustomerAddress { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(10)")]
        public string MobileNumber { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }

public class OrderMaster
    {
        [Key]
        public int OrderId { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
        public string ItemCode { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
        public string ItemName { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(MAX)")]
        public string ItemDescription { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
        public string Quantity { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
        public string OrderDate { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
        public string Amount { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
        public string CustomerCode { get; set; }

    }
```

this is my Context class

```
public class AppDbcontext : DbContext
    {
        public AppDbcontext(DbContextOptions<AppDbcontext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<CustomerMaster> CustomerDetails { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OrderMaster> OrderDetails { get; set; }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please share your models?

Comment: public class AppDbcontext : DbContext
    {
        public AppDbcontext(DbContextOptions<AppDbcontext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<CustomerMaster> CustomerDetails { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OrderMaster> OrderDetails { get; set; }

        }
    }                 //this is my modelcontext class

Comment: public class OrderMaster
    {
        [Key]
        public int OrderId { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
        public string ItemCode { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
        public string ItemName { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(MAX)")]
        public string ItemDescription { get; set; }

    }

Comment: public class CustomerMaster
    {
        [Key]
        public int CustomerCode { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
        public string CustomerAddress { get; set; }
    }

Comment: There are two model classes. I want to get both table details in one table.

Comment: Hi @Niranga,From your model design,which property in your two models are the relate key to combine the two tables?I provide a simple demo below you could follow.

Comment: Yes both tables have comman column for get details. [Customer_ID] .Ok thanks I will follow it

Comment: Now you can see my code clearly. But how to call [httpget] method as mentioned above?

Comment: Hi @Niranga,please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For how to join two tables,a simple demo you could follow:

```
var model = (from a in _context.CustomerDetails 
            join b in _context.OrderDetails 
            on a.ID equals b.ID
            select  new { 
                    Name = a.Name,
                    Address = b.Address
            }).ToList();
```

Update 1:

You use left join sql,you need change like below:

```
var model = (from a in _context.OrderDetails
                join b in _context.CustomerDetails
                on a.CustomerCode equals b.CustomerCode.ToString() into ab
                from b in ab.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new
                {
                    ItemDescription = a.ItemDescription,
                    Quantity = a.Quantity,
                    Amount = a.Amount,
                    CustomerCode = a.CustomerCode,
                    CustomerName = b.CustomerName,
                    CustomerAddress = b.CustomerAddress,
                    MobileNumber = b.MobileNumber,
                    Email = b.Email,
                }).ToList();
```

**Update 2**:

For how to return the two tables data,I think a better way is to create a view model to display:

```
public class OrderDetailViewModel
{
    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Amount { get; set; }
    public string CustomerCode { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerAddress { get; set; }
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }  
}
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<OrderDetailViewModel> GetOrderDetails()
{
    var model = (from a in _context.OrderDetails
                    join b in _context.CustomerDetails
                    on a.CustomerCode equals b.CustomerCode.ToString() into ab
                    from b in ab.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new OrderDetailViewModel
                    {
                        ItemDescription = a.ItemDescription,
                        Quantity = a.Quantity,
                        Amount = a.Amount,
                        CustomerCode = a.CustomerCode,
                        CustomerName = b.CustomerName,
                        CustomerAddress = b.CustomerAddress,
                        MobileNumber = b.MobileNumber,
                        Email = b.Email,
                    }).ToList();
    return model;
}
```

Comment: Yeaahhhh That is work... Thank you sooooo muchhh.........

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the two models connected through navigation properties. Something like

```
public class Table1 {
    int Table1Id;
    string Name;
    ICollection<Table2> Tables2;
}

public class Table2 {
    int Table2Id;
    string Address;
    Table1 Table1;
}
```

Then you can have your business layer code

```
[HttpGet]
... GetNameWithAddresses(int id) {
    return (from c in _context.Table1 where c.Table1Id == id
        select new { c.Name, c.Tables2 }).ToList();
}
```

If the tables have primary-foreign key relationship, it will be done automatically for you if you scaffold them. And if you don't have FK relationship, you have to ask yourself *why*!

Comment: Now I Created foreign key relationship by using navigation properties.                                                                                                                  [HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<OrderMaster>>> GetOrderDetails(int id)
{
    return (from c in _context.Table1 where c.Table1Id == id
        select new { c.Name, c.Tables2 }).ToList();
}

Comment: Can you sent public async Task<ActionResult<OrderMaster>> GetOrderMaster(int id){} this method. It show some errors.

Comment: @Niranga, Because you use `select new{}`,it will retrun an anonymous type.So it does not match your return type `OrderMaster`.If the two tables have relationship by navifation,no need use anonymous type,just use something  like `select new OrderMaster{...}`.

Comment: @Niranga - it would be helpful to go through Entity Framework tutorial first. Some of your questions would be obvious after that. Microsoft docs have pretty good ones, and anything from Julia Lerner is excellent. Your questions cannot be answered without more fundamental understanding of EF, which you don't have right now. It's not an insult - we've all been there :)

Comment: Ahh, it's Ok my friend. I am studying these fundamentals in ER. Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
using (var context = new AppDbcontext())
{
   var table1 = context.CustomerDetails.ToList();  
   var table2 = context.OrderDetails.ToList();  
}
```